# UICollectionView cell size - swift 3/4

Tags: swift, collectionview

I am working on Collection view.I want to display 3 rows in collection view . Each row having two cells.The problems is i can't able to fit the cells in a row.Please kindly refer my code which i tried.

```
import UIKit

class ProductsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var productsCollections: UICollectionView!
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    productsCollections.isScrollEnabled = false
    productsCollections.dataSource = self as? UICollectionViewDataSource
    productsCollections.delegate = self as? UICollectionViewDelegate
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

}

extension ProductsTableViewCell: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 6
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Product", for: indexPath)
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: 10)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return collectionView.frame.width/9
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return collectionView.frame.width
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let collectionViewWidth = collectionView.bounds.width
    let collectionViewHeight = collectionView.bounds.height
    return CGSize(width: collectionViewWidth/2.0 , height: collectionViewHeight/2.5)
}

 [This is the output i got.][1]}
```

[I want like this.totally 6 rows.Per row 2 cells i want to display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvg8j.png)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, calculate a row height that you need. So it is depends on screen resolution.

for example :

1- Declare a variable

```
fileprivate var cellHeight: CGFloat
```

2- calculate it once in viewDidLoad()

```
self.cellHeight = yourContainerFrameHeight / 3
```

3- Remove `minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt`

4- Calculate cell size.

I'm not sure, but you should not use the size of the CollectionView here (in `sizeForItemAt`). Instead you can use a fixed UIView or screen sizes. Because we already identify it.
This example has `self.contentView` you must change with yours or screen size

And try this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    flowLayout.invalidateLayout()
    let vMiddle = self.contentView.frame.size.width / 2.0
    //this calculation for prevent next row shifts and fit rows
    let cellWidth =  
        indexPath.row % 2 == 0 ? floor(vMiddle) : self.contentView.frame.size.width  - floor(vMiddle)
    //print("---------- cell width : \(cellWidth)")
    return CGSize(width: cellWidth, height: self.cellHeight)
}
```